# Reap and Sow Tags. How to retrieve part of list belonging to specific tag?

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap

I'm trying to improve my code's performance by using reap and sow instead of appendto and it works, but I hit a small obstacle. Since my code is building two lists simultaneously, I need to use sow with tag and afterwards I take the two resulting things from it. But I don't know which is which! I used tag to construct the lists so it seems natural to expect I would be able to call the parts of the output with that tag, like outputlist[[ tag used ]] or something similar. But I couldn't find anything like it.

The best solution I can think of is to just add a token element to each tag and I know that the list with a first element "this is from tag 1" is the tag 1 list. But if there's a more elegant way of doing that it would be nice.

Comment: Example? -- or maybe `Reap[<code>, {"tag1", "tag2"}]`?

Comment: You can turn the second element in the output of `Reap` into an `Association`. Then you can access the tags as desired.

Comment: Look at the docs for [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) under "Scope", "Generalizations & Extensions" and "Properties & Relations" -- there's one relevant example in each section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that Carl Woll constructed a minimal example, I can expand on my comment. You can turn the result of `Reap` into an association and access the tagged bins by using the tag as key:

```
harvest = Association@Reap[
     Sow[1, "tag1"];
     Sow[2, "tag1"];
     Sow[3, "tag2"],
     {"tag1", "tag2"},
     Rule][[2]]
```

> <|"tag1" -> {1, 2}, "tag2" -> {3}|>

Now you can access the binned data as follows:

```
harvest[["tag1"]]
harvest[["tag2"]]
```

> {1, 2}
>
> {3}

The `Sow`-and-`Reap` mechanisms is much older (version 5.0?) than `Association` (version 10.0). I bet that `Reap` would have been implemented to return an association if it would have been added to the language after `Association`. Now, it has to remain as it is for backward compatibility.

Caution: Be careful with integers as keys for an association: `heavest[[1]]`, `heavest[1]`, and `heavest[[Key[1]]]` behave quite differently when you use integer keys.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can tweak the following to suit your purposes:

```
Reap[
    Sow[1,"tag1"]; Sow[2,"tag1"]; Sow[3,"tag2"],
    {"tag1", "tag2"},
    Rule
]
```

> {3, {{"tag1" -> {1, 2}}, {"tag2" -> {3}}}}